# Android Studio not finding XML Preview to set surface provider

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to call my Preview View and execute the following code:

fun startCamera(){
val cameraProviderFuture =  ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

```
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        // Preview                        
        val preview = Preview.Builder(findViewById<View>(R.id.viewPreview))
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(ViewPreview.surfaceProvider)
            }
```

The problem I have is when trying to use Preview Builder to set Surface Provider for Preview View in XML I get unresolved reference for .surfaceProvider.

How can I set the surfaceProvider for the Preview View successfully?

Comment: I managed to resolve the problem with the following code:                   val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        val preview = (findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.viewPreview))



        cameraProviderFuture.addListener( {

            val cameraProvider:ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

             val preview = Preview.Builder()
                 .build()
                 .also {
                 it.setSurfaceProvider(preview.surfaceProvider)
                     }

Comment: If possible, writing this out as an answer and formatting it would be greatly appreciative!